# Why does shorthand if assignment to list not work?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Trying to use the code given below I get the error: `row[0] = "M" if row[0] == "male" else row[0] = "F" ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: cannot assign to subscript here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?`

```
rows = []
    for row in csvreader:
        row[0] = "M" if row[0] == "male" else row[0] = "F"
        rows.append(row)
```

However when I format it normally(see below) the error does not occur. Why is that?

```
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] == "male":
            row[0] = "M"
        else:
            row[0] = "F"
        rows.append(row)
```

Note: row is list of strings

Looking online at the error given it says it occurs because of an assignment to a literal, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is how to write the ternary expression

```
for row in csvreader:
    row[0] = "M" if row[0] == "male" else "F"
    rows.append(row)
```

#### The other method, less pythonic, is to use an if *statement*, and *two* assignments

```
for row in csvreader:
    if row[0] == "male":
        row[0] = "M"  
    else:
        row[0] = "F"
    rows.append(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem seems to be that I used row[0] = "F" in the else statement.

Comment: Yes - remember to mark as correct. 8-).